# In node.js, why is my data not getting passed back after a asynchronous file read using a Promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise, file-read

I know for sure that my pullData module is getting the data back from the file read but the function calling it, though it has an await, is not getting the data.

This is the module (./initialise.js) that reads the data:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const getData = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.readFile('./Sybernika.txt',
            { encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'r' },
            function (err, data) {
                if (err)
                    reject(err);
                else
                    resolve(data);
            });
    });
};

module.exports = {getData};
```

And this is where it gets called (app.js):

```
const init = require('./initialise');

const pullData = async () => {
    init.getData().then((data) => {
        return data;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

const start = async() => {
    let data = await pullData();
    console.log(data);
}

start();
```

putting 'console.log(data)' just before return(data) in the resolve part of the call shows the data so I know it's being read OK. However, that final console.log shows my data variabkle as being undefined.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `return` before `init.getData()` in `pullData`. Currently your `pullData` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either

```
const pullData = async () => {
  return init.getData().then((data) => {
    return data;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

or

```
const pullData = async () => 
  init.getData().then((data) => {
    return data;
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Both versions make sure a promise returned by `then`/`catch` is passed down to the caller.